ARRAYFORMULA in GOOGLE SHEETS
I am trying to count sequentially depends on the value using ArrayFormula to avoid manually dragging the column, I want to autofill everytime I add a value in Column A
in Column B - the ArrayFormula does not work
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I$1:I<>"", COUNTIF(I$1:I1, I1:I), ""))
in Column C - I tried to do it using
=COUNTIF(I$1:I1, I1:I)



A
B
C




A1
1
1


A1
1
2


A1
1
3


B1
0
1


B1
0
2


A2
0
1


A2
0
2



I tried to replicate the result in Column C using ArrayFormula but i couldn't do it.
Thank you.

Use a descriptive title please. See [ask]

Use the following formula in row 1 of an empty column:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I:I="",,COUNTIFS(I:I,I:I,ROW(I:I),"<="&ROW(I:I))))

You could also do it using MAP:
=MAP(I:I,LAMBDA(_,IF(_="",,COUNTIF(I1:_,_)))) 


it works, now in arrayformula, how to get the specific cell text? i am trying to concat, for example, in column A, the value in column B will be A1-01, and so on..

please create a new question
